# How to "Escape from All Foods" during "The Pickup" in Cyberpunk 2077?

Tags: cyberpunk-2077

I'm at the stage of "Escape all Foods" after a boss fight. My companion clipped through the closed, red door and I cannot escape. Since it's mark as "in combat" I cannot save and I cannot do anything else but go in circles. How to escape?

(I don't really want to reload a previous savegame as I don't want to do the boss fight again.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still have some enemies lying around somewhere alive. In my case, one was sort of hiding *under* a truck near a wall.

Once I killed the last enemy, the quest log updated and the door switched from red to green and I could open it.